# DebuggerDisplay Attribute does not work

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

This is a C++/CLI WinForms project targeting the .NET 2.0 framework. I am using Visual Studio 2008. How do I get it to work?

**EDIT:** Code snippet

```
[Serializable]
[DebuggerDisplayAttribute(L"ID={EmployeeID}")]
public ref class Employee
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    int nID;
    property int EmployeeID
    {
        int get()
        {
            return nID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code snippet?  What is failing?

Comment: It does not display the customized text just the usual: 
"employee = 0x058482f8 { age=46 tracker=0x0584f1cc nID=14 ...}"

Comment: Now supported in Update2 VS2015. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/12/natvis-for-ccli-available-to-preview-in-vs2015-update-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus is that the C++ IDE does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Define "doesn't work"... it certainly works in C# (I don't know if the C++ editor supports it - just translate the following which *works* in C# to find out ;-p)

```
using System.Diagnostics;
[DebuggerDisplay("HiWorld={Bar}")]
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { Bar = "abc" };
        // breakpoint and hover shows: HiWorld="abc"
    }
}
```

I don't "do" C++ any more, but reflector says:

```
[DebuggerDisplay(S"HiWorld={Bar}")]
private __gc class Foo
{
    // Methods
    private: static void __gc* Main()
    {
        Foo __gc* <>g__initLocal0 = __gc new Foo();
        <>g__initLocal0->Bar = S"abc";
        Foo __gc* foo = <>g__initLocal0;
    }


    // Properties
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public: __property String __gc* get_Bar()
    {
        return this-><Bar>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public: __property void __gc* set_Bar(String __gc* value)
    {
        this-><Bar>k__BackingField = value;
    }


    // Fields
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private: String __gc* <Bar>k__BackingField;
};
```

Comment: As far as I remember Reflector dissembles IL to something called Managed C++ which isn't regular C++/CLI. Am I right?

Comment: @abatishchev - certainly managed C++ is one of the options, but I can't comment on how this is/isn't standard C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you're specifying wide strings (`L"ID={EmployeeID}"`) instead of CLR strings (`S"ID={EmployeeID}"`). So perhaps change the L to an S and see how you go?